# Change RSS format for specific categories

Tags: categories, rss

Is there way to have, **in a single RSS feed**, different formats for different categories?

For example, if a post is a very long and technical one I would like to have only an excerpt (or a custom text with a link) and if it is short I would like to put the whole thing on the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is! WordPress has filters called `the_excerpt_rss` and `the_content_feed` which filter the posts' content and excerpts for the RSS feed. The filter is called in the loop, so you can use `get_the_ID()` and `get_the_content()` (and other loop functions) to fetch information about the post.

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'wpse151603_rss_post_excerpt' );

function wpse151603_rss_post_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    $content = get_the_content();

    if ( strlen( $content ) < 200 ) {
        $excerpt = get_the_content(); // Get full content for use in feed
    }

    return $excerpt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And in my case it will be `get_the_category()`